# What determines the size of the rdb R source database

Tags: r

A [package](https://github.com/flr/FLXSA/tree/master/R) with 40.3 Kb of R source code ends up once installed with a rbd file of 14.0 Mb. In comparison, data.table, where the R folder contains 393 Kb of code, ends up with an rdb file of 1.4 Mb once installed in Linux via R CMD build / INSTALL.

What could explain this difference? My package uses S4 classes, but even lme4 has an rdb file of 7.8 Mb from a total of 937 Kb of R code.

Is there anything I can do to make the database smaller?

Answer (score 1):

You can see what's taking up a large portion of the rdb file by reading the index. Here's a helper function

```
get_rdb_info <- function(packagename) {
  index <- readRDS(system.file(paste0("R/", packagename, ".rdx"), package=packagename))
  rbind(
  data.frame(
    type="variable",
    name = names(index$variables), 
    size = sapply(index$variables, `[`, 2)),
  data.frame(
    type="reference",
    name = names(index$references), 
    size = sapply(index$references, `[`, 2))
  )
}
```

And then you can use that with

```
stats <- get_rdb_info("lme4")
```

and see the largest items with

```
head(stats[order(stats$size, decreasing = TRUE), ])
```

Perhaps it's possible function closures are trapping large variables that you didn't intend.

The data should already be compressed. Just make sure you aren't creating large data object that live inside your package namespace.

Comment: I could not create the 'reference' data.frame, as size is not returned as a vector but a list when applied to lme4, and if converted to a vector, it is longer than names. How can I interpret the reference list? I get entries like `1:    env::1  206`.

Comment: You mean you get an error when you run the code I provided? It runs fine for me for `lme4`. The references contain environments created when your R code was run during the building of the package. If you really need to know more about how those data structures are organized, you'll probably want to ask for help on the `r-devel` mailing list: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel. As far as I know it's a private data structure that's not publicly documented.

Comment: I am afraid it fails here (R 4.0.4 on Linux), `Error in data.frame(type = "reference", name = names(index$references),: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 1731, 2`

Comment: That's odd. I also just tested on R 4.0.4 on linux (`lme4_1.1-26`) and it works fine. But still, I think the mailing list is the best place to get more details if you need to account for every byte.

Comment: Will do. I need to know if it matters, although the manual say packages with less than 10 Mb lazyload databases are cached in memory, so maybe there is some performance advantage at keeping it below that limit.